# How to split string in NSIS

Tags: nsis

String **"jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DatabaseName"**

My requirement is to get only the **DatabaseName** from the above string.

I tried below link but it is not worked.

```
${Explode} $0 "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/" "$v1"
```

It give the error invalid command.

http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Explode

How it is possible in NSIS language. As i'm not more familiar with NSIS language.
Please do the needful help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It started to work for me when I copied function definition [from mentioned site](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Explode)  into the script.

Comment: What if I want to get the path until jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432

Answer (score 5):

If all you need is to get the rest of the string after the last `/` you can just use some basic NSIS string handling:

```
Section

StrCpy $0 "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DatabaseName"
StrCpy $1 0
loop:
    IntOp $1 $1 - 1 ; Character offset, from end of string
    StrCpy $2 $0 1 $1 ; Read 1 character into $2, -$1 offset from end
    StrCmp $2 '/' found
    StrCmp $2 '' stop loop ; No more characters or try again
found:
    IntOp $1 $1 + 1 ; Don't include / in extracted string
stop:
StrCpy $2 $0 "" $1 ; We know the length, extract final string part
DetailPrint "|$2|"

SectionEnd
```

Comment: Thanks, but NSIS is hard for many programmers to read.  It would be very nice if you could explain what the looping is doing so others could adopt this example to their needs.  For example, is this a reverse-direction for loop, is that how it finds the last `/`?  If so, how does the loop grab each character?  Does the string (character array) behave like a counter?

Comment: @tresf Yes, it reads 1 character at the time, beginning at the end, and stops when that character (in $2) matches. `StrCpy` does this when you give it a negative start offset.

Answer (score 0):

You should try the [NSISpcre plugin](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/NSISpcre_plug-in), maybe you need some nasty regex :p

Comment: I'm not more familiar with NSIS language. Could please suggest me how to use in my code that function

Comment: Well, I'm not using Windows OS can't help you on that but you can try creating a sample nsis script plus the plugin and use it with the string line you need. Once you get the idea, put it in your main script. NSIS is mostly that, learn, try, trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

The [WordFind](https://github.com/NSIS-Dev/Documentation/blob/master/Includes/WordFunc/WordFind.md) function lets you do that, take a look at its examples